# the form does not print out the details

Tags: php, html, forms, oop, server-side

I have created a form in html which takes all the information using the method post in php to print them out for the user but its seems like that I have a problem with my form. It does not print out the entered details by the user, I have tried to fill up and then press submit to create an object of the class profile assigning all the information from the user to the object and print them out on the browser but nothing appear on the browser.

I have also tried to echo the methods like getFirstName but its the same nothing comes up, can anyone help me to find out whats the problem with the code and how can I fix it.

Please note that I have included three different files one is the html form and the other one is the passingdata.php which will get all the information entered by the user and the third file is the class profile which is used in the passingdata to create an object and give it all the needed information in order to create an object of that class.

Finally, I have invoked the method printDeatils which should print out all the information entered by the user

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo 'Student Deatils';     ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Please enter your Details:</p>
        <div>
        <form name="student" method="post" action="passingdata.php">
            <div>
            <label>First name:</label> <input type ="text" name="first_name"> 
            <label>Last name</label> <input type ="text" name="last_name"> 
            <br></br>
            <label>International student</label> <input type="checkbox" name="international">
              <br></br>
              <fieldset>
                  <legend>Course</legend>
            <label>CS <input type="radio" name="course" value="CS"></label> 
            <label>SE <input type="radio" name="course" value="SE"></label>
            <label>MIT <input type="radio" name="course" value="MIT"></label>

            </fieldset>
              <br></br>
              <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
              <input type="reset" name="Resit" value="Reset">
             </div>
        </form>
            </div>
        <?php


        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The passing data file:**

```
<?php
     require("profile.php");
    $ss = new Profile($_POST['first_name'], $_POST["last_name"], 
     $_POST["course"], $_POST["international"]);
     echo $ss->printDtails();
?>
```

**The class profile:**

```
<?php


class Profile {
    private  $_firstName, $_lastName, $_international, $_course;

    function __contruct ($firstName, $lastName, $course, $international) { 
$this->_firstName = $firstName; 
$this->_lastName = $lastName; 
$this->_course = $course; 
$this->_international = $international; 
}



    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->_firstName = $firstName; 

    }
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->_lastName = $lastName; 
    }
    public function setInternational($inter)
    {

          $this->_international = $inter; 
    }
    public function setCourse($course)
    {
           $this->_course = $course; 
    }
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->_firstName;
    }
      public function getLastName()
    {
          return $this->_lastName;
    }
      public function getInternational()
    {
       return $this->_international;
    }
    public function getCourse()
    {

        return $this->_course;
    }
    public function printDtails()
    {
        echo "$_firstName";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to echo `$this->_firstName` - you're using it properly in your setters and getters, but not in the print function.

Comment: $this->_firstName not $_firstName

Comment: i ve tried it but its not working

Comment: Misspelled `__contruct` change to `__construct` as noted in an answer below. @user3170512

Answer (score 0):

In the `printDtails()` function you need to `echo $this->_firstName`

Also in your class, the word construct is spelled wrong, you have `__contruct` it needs to be `__construct`

Comment: in your class the construct is spelled wrong, you have "__contruct" it needs to be "__construct"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, however I did modify your code slightly.

I must admit that I'm learning classes myself, so this may or may not be what you're looking for, however it did work.

Also, inside your `printDtails()` function, it needed a `echo $this->_firstName;` etc.

I changed your constructs to `$this->_firstName = $_POST['first_name'];` etc.

**N.B.:** The word `construct` was mispelled as `contruct` with the missing `s`

Here is what I came up with:

```
<?php

class Profile {

    private  $_firstName, $_lastName, $_international, $_course;
    function __construct ($_firstName, $_lastName, $_international, $_course)

{ 
$this->_firstName = $_POST['first_name']; // modified
$this->_lastName = $_POST['last_name']; // modified
$this->_course = $_POST['course']; // modified
$this->_international = $_POST['international']; // modified
}

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->_firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->_lastName = $lastName; 
    }
    public function setInternational($inter)
    {
          $this->_international = $inter; 
    }
    public function setCourse($course)
    {
           $this->_course = $course; 
    }
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->_firstName;
    }
      public function getLastName()
    {
          return $this->_lastName;
    }
      public function getInternational()
    {
       return $this->_international;
    }
    public function getCourse()
    {
        return $this->_course;
    }
    public function printDtails()
    {
    echo $this->_firstName . "\n"; // modified
    echo $this->_lastName . "\n"; // modified
    echo $this->_course . "\n"; // modified
    echo $this->_international . "\n"; // modified
    }
}

?>
```